# Angular 8 static query usage and migration from Angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular8

I am seeing a crash in a component usage when I use {static: true}

```
 Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Component code looks like this

```
@ViewChild('filterInput', {static: true}) filterInputElement: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.inputNodeRef = this.filterInputElement.nativeElement;
}
```

My expectation based on the documentation here is that when I say {static: true}, my ViewChild is safe to access and use in ngAfterViewInit because it became available much earlier in ngOnInit - https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Is this understanding incorrect?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your template? `static` flag represent if the element available dynamically or not i.e. element rendering depends on some value evaluated on some expression for which the value will be evaluated later (i.e. `*ngIf`). In your case, we will be able to help if you share your template.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by making the static flag false and I think I understand it now. The thing is I found this portion of the documentation confusing - https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

*****************************************************
// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;

OR

// query results available in ngAfterViewInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
*****************************************************
I thought using {static: true} can never go wrong because ngOnInit runs first.